# Apache Dynamic Virtual Host

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Hello I am currently hosting a site on Amazon EC2. Love it but am having a bit of trouble with my httpd.conf file.

**The Problem:**

I am hosting many websites. Some need to be dynamic and some can be static. For example I have  dogs.com and cats.com however, I need dogareawesomeinNH.com and dogareawesomeinNY.com and dogareawesomeinFL.com to all be routed to the same virtual host.

**Attempted Try:**

I have looked into doing "Dynamic Virtual Hosts with mod_vhost_alias" but I don't know if this is the right solution because I need some things mapped to the same folder.

**My Question:**

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

*the dog and cat references are obviously not my domains.*

Comment: It would be best to ask this question at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I will do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamic virtual hosts apache

## See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%0/htdocs/
```

Enable mod_vhost_alias by uncommenting this line in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```